# Assign a unique integer to an alphanumeric string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data of order `4096*2` in excel. Second column contains all alphanumeric values of the kind `10ABC1101, 10CDE1101 and 20FGH2345`. I am looking for a method (using Excel functions only and not VBA) to assign a unique integer value to each alphanumeric value in column 2.

Plan is to take data into Matlab for some analysis (and avoid String handling within Matrices) and bring it back to Excel and convert integers into original alphanumeric strings.

***Ps:*** I am new to both Matlab and Excel.

Clearly separating numbers from strings will not help me because that does not assign unique value.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Is each value only once in column 2?

Comment: No, all of them repeat, with frequency ranging from 5 up to near 100.

Comment: If the values repeat, do you want them to have the same integer value?  What is the maximum number of characters?

Comment: Yes. Because when I convert them back into alphanumeric, it will give me exactly what I started with. Actually there are two files. One with strings like **ABCD1234** and the other with strings like **10ABCD1234**. So both have four characters in the string.

Comment: @Guest If MatLab can handle large enough values, you could just concatenate the two digit ASCII codes for the characters (characters = digit or letter)

Comment: May I ask why my question has been voted down? May be because it was too easy for experts. Or may be because who ever did it was thinking, I didn't try at all to find the solution. Well if it helps, I can share my web history log to prove that I did try my best to find the answer, but I could not. That is when I decided to ask some experts. I thought it qualifies for such help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-consecutive Unique IDs you can use (in column `C`)

```
=MATCH(B:B,B:B,0)
```

To get the string back

```
=INDEX(B:B,C:C)
```

Note: these formulas use **Implicit Intersection** [see here for some info](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-14-handling-whole-columns-using-implicit-intersection/)